# Do I really need a managed bean?

Tags: xpages

Everyting I have read about calling Java from Xpages mentions managed beans.   But I really don't need to save the state of my object.  Do I still need to make my class managed?

What I need to do is to check to see if a password is expired for a user in Directory Services (LDAP).  My plan was to check the state using my LDAP class then store the result in a regular session variable.  So would I still need to use a managed bean?

If not, do I still need to mention the class in faces-config.xml or anyplace  else?

Comment: The short answer: no, you don't need a bean. You can call your java class directly instead (by referencing the complete package name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Henrik said you dont need to use a bean. 
Here a short example how to call a java class directly. Lets say your class is in the package `org.test`in Path: 
**yourApplication.nsf/webContent/WEB-INF/src/**

```
package org.test;

public class Test{

    public static String halloWorld() throws Exception {
        return "HalloWorld";
    }
}
```

you can call its Methods by using:

```
<xp:text value="#{javascript:return org.test.Test.halloWorld();}"></xp:text>
```

You can find more Infos on that in the [IBM wiki.](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/09242008095047AMWEBJ9A.htm)